# How to get a correct result of a model getSize() after a getSelect()->limit()

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

*Hello,*

Currently, I try to create a custom advanced search in order to **show only X specific products**.

When my model is filtered and they are more than the number expected, I limit them with :

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(X);
$collection->load();
```

If I check with a `count($collection)`, I get without surprise X.
But, if I check with a `$collection->getSize()`, I get the exact previous number **as if I hadn't done the limit**(X).

Is there a way to "force" the getSize() to **consider the limit**, or a way to **limit the product collection** in order to get a correct size ?

*Thanks you for your time,*

PS:

- Tried with `$collection->setPage(0,X)`
- Tried with `$collection->setPageSize(X)->setCurPage(1);`
- I use a singleton of Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced rewrited
- This singleton collection get filtered with addFilters() and work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use: $collection->count();

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$collection->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get the same result as setPage(0,5) or limit(5). There is 5 products shown but much more as a result of getSize().

Any other ideas please ?

Comment: Are you sure there is no other mistake? If you use the code I gave you and then `print_r( $collection->getAllIds() );` what is the output?

Comment: getAllIds() of this $collection give me an array of 62 product's Id. There surely is a mistake if it doesn't work as it should, but I clearly don't see it.

I updated my post with some more informations in post-scriptum in case that could help. Thank you for your help.